# Getx await to build the list

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a method need to be first executed to get the items before construct the ListView.builder, how to keep this method always executed before the ListView?

```
class TestModel extends GetxController {
  final items = <Item>[].obs;

  void init() async {
    items.value = getRemoteItems();
  }
}

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final TestModel testModel = Get.put(TestModel());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (testModel.items.isEmpty) {
      testModel.init(); // It seems the ListView can not get the testModel's items.
    }

    return Obx(
      () => ListView.builder(
        itemCount: testModel.items.length, // But the items length is always 0.
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = testModel.items[index];
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you can't do that but you can update your ui when it occurs. Can you try this?

```
class TestModel extends GetxController {
   final items = <Item>[];
   String token = ''; //if it's dynamic, don't do this...

   void onInit() {
      // this runs your method at the beginning
      // but if you wanna aviod this, 
      // you can remove here.
      foo();
   }

   void foo(
           String token //...do this and run this with token.
        ) async {
     items.value = await getRemoteItems(token);
     update();
   }
}

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    final TestModel testModel = Get.put(TestModel());

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if (testModel.items.isEmpty) {
         testModel.foo();
         return Container(); // or loading screen.
      }

      return GetxController<TestModel>(
         builder: (_) => ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _.items.length, 
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         final item = _.items[index];
...
    }
   }
```

Comment: If the foo method need with the argument like `foo(String token)`, how to add this action?

Comment: Hey @ccd! I edited code for you. You can check it again.

Answer (score 1):

I think Getx changed the Lifecycle.(I'm a beginner, please correct my mistake if exists)

If you use StatefulWidget, then the Widget's Lifecycle would be like this:

```dart
StatefulWidget -> [State<T> -> initState() -> build(context)]
```

But if you use Getx for substituting StatefulWidget into StatelessWidget, that's:

```dart
StatelessWidget -> Get.put() -> GetxController.onInit() -> StatelessWidget.build(context)
```

Use `StateWidget` means you need to use `setState()`, but you could init your datas with more flexible code in `initState()`

Use `GetxController + StatelessWidget`, for binding the Widget and Datas, the only way is write code like this:

```dart
class PostsList extends StatelessWidget {
    final postsController =
      Get.put(MyController("My Init Query"));
      // trigger the GetxController onInit() with returning datas back to postsController 
...
```

I've just come across a problem: if I have to init 2 or more GetxController and they have a Data dependencies, what should I do?

```dart
class PostsList extends StatelessWidget {
    final postsController = Get.put(MyController("My Init Query"));
    final aUserController = Get.put(postsController[0].user_id));
//Error: The instance member 'postsController' can't be accessed in an initializer.
```

It's still hard for me to deal with the sync/async Function, which Future<> would always executes after the sync code. You always need to deal with the null situation, wichi increased my coding workload a lot.

So in the end, I use StatefulWidget+State :(